# angularjs add css property to element without jquery

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

In an angular directive I am making a clone of the element that I want which is

```
var node= element[0].cloneNode(true);
```

then I want to add css to this element.  I know you can do this

```
$(node).css({width: width, left: left, height: height, top:'0px'});
```

but I know it is bad practice to use this in an angular directive.  I have tried

```
angular.node.css({width: width, left: left, height: height, top:'0px'});
```

but this does not work.  I have scoured the internet and have found nothing.  All I get is jquery ways.  Does anyone know how to add css to an element the angular way?

To any help, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular comes with [jqLite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), which is a trimmed down version of jQuery. There's nothing wrong with using it in a directive. `clone()` and `css()` are available in jqLite...

```
var node = element.clone()
                  .css({width: width, left: left, height: height, top:'0px'});
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/yowubixa/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks @anthony, I thought this would work, but I still get a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined' error.  Do you know what this could mean?

Comment: Can you post your code, maybe in a fiddle? I just tried this in the link function of a directive and it worked.

Comment: @user3339134 Updated answer with the example.

Comment: that is weird, it works on jsbin, but I am still getting 'css' of undefined.  Weird.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: What you said seems to work.  Kind of.  The reasons it might not work, may be on my part.  In my directive when I print console.log(element[0].parentElement) I get the dom, but what I want is the array like thing that has children and offset.  How do I print that info of a parent.  By the way, since I think this works I am going to set this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ngStyle` directive takes an "Expression which evals to an object whose keys are CSS style names and values are corresponding values for those CSS keys."

Comment: Thanks for responding @phylax.  But, I am doing all the values in javascript/directive so I can't use ngStyle

Answer (score 0):

To those who may find this later, I found the solution to my problem.  The reason why I could not do node.css() was because node was a dom element.  This was due to my copy.  To keep the javascript object you have to do

```
angular.element(element[0]).clone()
```

to properly clone it.  this then allows me to do node.css().  You can do other things besides .css.  You can look at the following here.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

open ....component.js

> `angular.element(idName).css("background", "#000");`

i.e hello is idName in div.

`<div id="hello"></div>`